# What's the C++ equivalent of this matlab code (fread matlab vs fread C/C++)?

Tags: c++, c, file

Trying to convert this matlab code:

```
fid = fopen([fpath, '/file.bin'],'rb');
content = fread(fid, 11,'single');
```

My current attempt is the following:

```
FILE* f = fopen(filename.c_str(),"rb");
char *content = (char*) malloc (sizeof(float)*11);
size_t result;
result = fread(content,4,11,f);
```

Which make sense to me but it doesn't work.

**Update**:

The first line of the file is supposed to be something like:

`120.0 120.0 120.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 0.05000000074505806 0.25 2.0 2.0 2.0`

I've also checked of the `f` pointer is `NULL`, and it isn't. When I open the file and load the content, and later print it it doesn't show anything.

Comment: what is the meaning of "doesn't work" ? Do you want C or C++? Your code looks like C with a sprinkle of C++

Comment: Title says C++, code says C (OK, it’s probably *compiled* as C++, but it’s really mostly C), tags say both.

Comment: @Biffen `filename.c_str()` i wouldnt bet, but thats probably a `std::string`

Comment: Did you check if the FILE pointer `f` is not `NULL`?

Comment: Related: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: It doesn't work means if I run the matlab I see the expected line if I print it. If I run the C++ it doesn't print anything, which is odd given it is applied to the same file.

Comment: @AmeyaVS, it isn't `NULL`.

Comment: @user463035818, for this specific bit, yes they're both. But if there's a better way using `fstream` etc, I'm totally fine.

Comment: @user8469759 What are you trying to print in C++? There is just too little context with the question.

Comment: From the output of the matlab they're `11` floating point numbers, and these should give me information to read the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use input streams.

E.g. to read one line

```
std::ifstream f(filename);
std::array<float, 11> content;
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<float>(f), 11, content.begin());
```

or multiple

```
std::ifstream f(filename);
std::vector<std::array<float, 11>> content;
for (std::string line; std::getline(f, line);) {
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    std::array<float, 11> datum;
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<float>(f), 11, datum.begin());
    content.push_back(datum);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why am I getting all zeroes. `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Comment: if you add `std::cout << line << std::endl;` in the loop, do you see lines from your file in your output?